# Boost asio send and receive messages

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to send and receive messages from a client and server using TCP. I'm trying it with threading, and I don't know how to do this at all. I can connect to the server just fine, but I need to be able to send and receive messages from both places on demand. I've been searching for hours and have come up empty, as all of the results on Google are overcomplicated and cluttering.

```
struct Client
{
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;

Client(const char* host = HOST, const char* port = PORT) : socket(io_service) 
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint = resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query(HOST, PORT));
    boost::asio::connect(this->socket, endpoint);
   };
};
```

That's all I have so far for the client.

For the server:

```
const int PORT = 52275;

int main()
{
    try
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), PORT));

    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        acceptor.accept(socket);
        main();
    }
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
}
```

Comment: All the results you would sollicit here, you would find "overcomplicated and cluttering". For the simple reason that they - too - would necessarily not fit your framework of reference/code context. Main reason for this is: you don't share any of your context code. (_Now, you're safe, because **no one** will spend an hour re-inventing one of those examples just for you, just because you don't like the existing samples. That'd be a waste of time._)

Comment: I'm not asking for an entire explanation to be recreated for me, rather, a simple example or explanation of communication. I've tried adapting the examples I've found, but all of them have resulted in errors. I'm not an expert in C++, but I'm not so new that I need everything made for me. Boost asio is hardly documented.

Comment: [Really](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9632633/)? As you mention in your question, the thing you're asking for exists in many places. SO is a place where you ask concrete programming questions. So, tell us what you are stuck at. We're not going to google for nice examples without any context. You can do that a lot better.

Comment: I am stuck at being able to send messages between the client and the server, and allow for callback functions to be used. I have said that before. You are overthinking this. I have given context to the code. I have not asked for anyone to Google any examples, I've asked for someone to provide an example or explanation, and you continue to act as if the only thing I want to do is have someone Google something for me.

Comment: _"I can connect to the server just fine, but I need to be able to send and receive messages from both places on demand"_ You pose a very broad, unclear question. If you need a lot of things, how can I deduce you just want to sent `n` bytes? I won't assume such things.

Comment: I don't understand how you are not understanding. Do you know what a message is? Do you know what it means to send something? Where am I losing you?

Comment: Do you show what your message is? Do you show what you're even sending? (Does your code compile?) What does it mean "from both places"? What does "on demand" mean?

Comment: I'm not asking how to send an exact message, I'm asking how to send **A** message. The code compiles, and obviously when I'm talking about client and server communications and mention "both places" I mean both the client and server. I'm beginning to think you are purposely playing dumb, as I've made it very clear what I need help with. If you're not going to offer some sort of assistance, please, just don't bother.

Comment: It's rather unthankful to scold me for "playing dumb" and "being unhelpful". Right now, I'm *the only one* trying to be of help here. Think about it. (I think it's just be experience that tells us - the SO community members - when the problem is unclear. Helping you formulate the problem is also beneficial to you, and avoids wasting time).

Comment: @sehe Thanks for the effort.  I too found the question difficult to answer.  I try to avoid code only answers in hopes that an accompanying explanation will teach someone something: how to use the documentation, how to use the library, best practices, concepts, etc.  When someone has done research that yields overcomplicated results, without context on _what_ the researcher finds overcomplicated, I struggle to get the right level of detail for the answer to be helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since it's apparently safe to assume you just want to send /any/ message by the simplest means possible:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94b81add86416068)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

struct Client
{
    boost::asio::io_service& io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;

    Client(boost::asio::io_service& svc, std::string const& host, std::string const& port) 
        : io_service(svc), socket(io_service) 
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint = resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query(host, port));
        boost::asio::connect(this->socket, endpoint);
    };

    void send(std::string const& message) {
        socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(message));
    }
};


#include <iostream>

static const int PORT = 52275;

void client_thread() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    Client client(svc, "127.0.0.1", std::to_string(PORT));

    client.send("hello world\n");
    client.send("bye world\n");
}

void server_thread() {
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), PORT));

        {
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);

            boost::asio::streambuf sb;
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            while (boost::asio::read(socket, sb, ec)) {
                std::cout << "received: '" << &sb << "'\n";

                if (ec) {
                    std::cout << "status: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::thread_group tg;
    tg.create_thread(server_thread);

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    tg.create_thread(client_thread);

    tg.join_all();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed. The only other thing I'm having trouble with is a receiving callback on the server, so that when the server receives a message, it can print the message to the console, for example.

Comment: @TidasBay I believe you. Yet, there is no server.

Comment: @TidasBay You do realize that this is a completely separate question then, right? Anyhoops: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94b81add86416068).

Comment: Yeah, but I thought I might as well try and get rid of them both at the same place. I can work with this information, thanks for your help. It's appreciated.

Comment: @TidasBay You can. Next time, try to make sure the question is complete in the first place so we can be a lot more to the point. If a question changes significantly, it's good netiquette to post another. Cheers